# Upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 14.10 Network-Manager fails to start on boot

Tags: 14.04, 14.10

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 14.10. Since the upgrade, the Network-Manager service fails to start on boot. I have checked the `syslog` and noticed the following errors.

```
nm-dispatcher.action: Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01ifupdown' exited with error status 1.

NetworkManager[3258]: <warn> Dispatcher script failed: Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01ifupdown' exited with error status 1.

ntpd_intres[1617]: parent died before we finished, exiting
```

I am able to start the network if I enter either of the following commands.

```
sudo service network-manager start
sudo initctl emit static-network up
```

Based on other forum posts and what I've found myself, the Network-Manager service fails to start because static-network-up fails to start. Based on the file `/etc/init/network-manager.conf`, there is a condition in the "start on" section that is contingent on static-network-up starting. However, I'm unable to figure out why this service is not starting.

Any help is greatly appreciated.