# boot hangs at different points

Tags: boot, grub2, 17.10, startup, grubrescue

Not sure how or why, but was able to boot after n'th time.

I updated `/etc/default/grub` to remove "quiet" and "splash" and then ran `sudo update-grub` and `reboot`.  Boot hangs on:

`Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...`

There are some google results, but nothing I saw specific to Ubuntu and relevant.

see also:

[Ubuntu 16.10 freezes at startup](https://askubuntu.com/q/850181/45156)

[Upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 14.10 Network-Manager fails to start on boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/607141/45156)